# Question about Rings and Fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

We have proved before that $\mathbb Q$ is a prime field. Can we say the same for $\mathbb R$ (prime field)? Using the same proof we used for $\mathbb Q$?

Thank you.

Comment: What are $R$ and $Q$ here?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani $Q$ rational numbers and $R$ are real numbers.

Comment: The prime subfield of a field is the smallest subfield that contains $1$.  For $\mathbb R$, the prime subfield is $\mathbb Q$.  If you have some other definition of "prime" to use here, include that in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A field is prime if and only if it has no proper subfields. $\mathbb R$ has $\mathbb Q$ as a proper subfield, so it is not prime. Looking at it another way, nontrivial extensions of prime fields (like $\mathbb R$ is of $\mathbb Q$) cannot be prime, since they always have their prime field as a proper subfield.

Comment: thank you so much! I don't know why I didn't think of that it was easy, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Prime fields are $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some prime $p$, depending on whether $1$ has finite additive order or not...None of them are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: so what you're saying is $\mathbb{R}$ is not a prime field? $\mathbb{R}$ is not a prime field because it contains $\mathbb{Q}$ which is a proper subfield, right?